# Sending mail address as parameter in MVC5 causes site crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been following this tutorial on [Extending Identity Accounts and Implementing Roles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role?msg=4719497#xx4719497xx). I didn´t implement some Delete methods I don´t need and I set ApplicationUser.userName attribute to be an email address. Those are restrictions of my project.

Everything is working fine except user edition and role assignation.

Once I load the Index of the AccountController Myhost/Account it shows this

[image: http://local:17353/Account]

But Whenever I try to click on Edit or Roles links, it crashes weirdly, like this. Myhost/Account/Edit/username%40gmail.com

[image: Myhost/Account/Edit/username%40gmail.com]

I just realize this system is in spanish so I translate the error here.
Error HTTP 404.0 - Not FOund
The resource you look for has been removed, it name changed or is not available right now.

Causes
Specified Directory or file is not on the server
url address has type error
A filter, customized module, as URLScan, restricts file access

What you can try
Create content on the web server
Check url on the browser
Check registry of erroneous calls to see which module calls SetStatus. To get more information click here (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439)

Error detiled information

I´ll just put the labels.

Module
Notification
controller. StatisFile (this is not a controller in my website)
error code
requested url
physic access route
session start method
session start user
Calls Directory

end of error

However, the problem is on the urland is caused by the @ symbol in the url. If I rewrite the url as Myhost/Account/Edit?username=username%40gmail.com the edit form is loaded correctly.

[image]

How can I force the parameter to go as a querystring parameter? or, is there a way to make theserver understand the mail address in the standard way?

The method invoked is this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Edit(string userName, ManageMessageId? Message = null)
{
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);
        var model = new EditUserViewModel(user);
        ViewBag.MessageId = Message;
        return View(model);
}
```

UPDATE
As you asked in the comments, here is the Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<CAEWebSite.Models.EditUserViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Usuarios</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Nuevo usuario", "Register")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecondLastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecondLastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.UserName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Roles", "UserRoles", new { id = item.UserName }) |
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is my RouteConfig class, pretty much as VS generated it

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

Comment: How is your form setup? Because when you use models for mvc with a form and formmethod POST then theoretically you shouldn't have a problem with this. Could you show us the cshtml code?

Comment: I just updatedthe question including the full cshtml of the Account Controller Index

Comment: Does it work if you add <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" /> to your web.config?

Comment: No it doesn't. :( My config is like this: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

Comment: How does your routing definition look like?

Comment: If you mean which routes I have in the routes List? none. I tried adding a route but I got an exception for Route can not have a ? symbol.

Comment: Please post your current Route setup and what is `ManageMessageId`. I assume it is a struct, but somehow it just feels like you want to pass just an integer instead. Also it is absolutely weird to have `id = item.UserName` while the action/method accepts `userName`.

Comment: I just posted it as second update. And I have this variable named id just because the tutorial was mistaken too but it is intended to send the username not the id. Mostly for not having database identification numbers going on the wild un protected. It is following some practices of Microsoft guys and design.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard routing set up: Try to change the

```
public ActionResult Edit(string userName, ManageMessageId? Message = null)
```

to:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, ManageMessageId? Message = null)
```

Just to see if it works. If it does, the reason it fails now is that the routing expects a parameter that is called id.

Comment: As I exposed in the comments. it is intended to send username not id but the variable name is misstyped. I don´t think this can actually throw the error. What the compiler cares about how I named it?

Comment: default routing looks for a parameter called id. Hence renaming the parameter could confirm or reject my theory of a routing issue. If you try this and it works I can give you some tips on how to change the behavior to fit your requirements.